# c++ edit text on another program window from its memory

Tags: c++, memory, text, readprocessmemory

I want to edit text in another program ui element
this is easy if the window has a handle so I can use SetWindowText() function

but some windows doesn't have handles as they are windowless so I can't access the elements in them

I tried to use ReadProcessMemory to find the text I'm searching for and edit it with WriteProcessMemory but I can't find the string in the memory , I also used a program called heapmemview but also I didn't get the readable text I look for , so where is this text as I know it must be in the memory of the process but it doesn't apear to be there

Comment: What about using interprocess communication? Use sockets for example (but there may be simpler techiniques). Because you may need to notify the other process to update its UI according to the new value, not just change the memory contents.

Comment: How did you search for the text? It may be stored in ASCII, or it may possibly be in "Unicode" (wide/UTF16) format, which some search functions might not catch...

Comment: A windowless UI may support [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) (which you should be using anyway).

Answer (score 0):

> can't find the string in the memory

The string must exist in memory, it is most likely a Unicode string and you're searching for an ANSI string.

For the purpose of this answer, unicode chars are 2 bytes while the ANSI chars are 1 byte.

If you're searching for the value in Cheat Engine then you need to check the 'unicode' option.

When you go to overwrite that memory, make sure your source buffer is a wchar_t array not a char array and make sure you use sizeof() not strlen() so you get the correct size in bytes.  Also make sure you use a null terminator, assuming it's a null terminated string.